# How to detect BPM of audio file in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avfoundation

I tried to find BPM using `AVFoundation` framework but getting `0` as a result and not able to get BPM.

Here is my code,

```
MPMediaItem * mediaItem = [[collection items] objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString * albumIDKey = [MPMediaItem persistentIDPropertyForGroupingType: MPMediaGroupingAlbum];
NSLog(@"mpmediaitem:%@", albumIDKey);
int BPM = [[mediaItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute] intValue];
NSString * bpm = [mediaItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyBeatsPerMinute];
NSLog(@"bpm:%@", bpm);
NSURL * url = [mediaItem valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
```

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: your question is rather hard to answer, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you are that the audio file has data in it? Can you show the code you used - and how you conclude the value is zero? There are soooo many different ways this can go wrong. Please show full code sample!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BPM is extracted from the metadata accompanying the audio file. Which often is not present.  It is not calculated from the audio.

Also be aware that any BPM metadata that does exist is flawed by the assumption that a track has a constant tempo.  Not always a safe assumption.

Quality audio-metadata can be obtained from [The Echonest](http://echonest.com)

Comment: The link you provided is not working. I am facing the same problem of bpm coming as 0 everytime. Please suggest some useful resources.